# Django annotate by calculated field in extra select

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have People model with City and Age fields.
I need to get count of people in each city segmented by 3 different age ranges < 20, between 20 and 50 and > 50. I need do this in one SQL query.

```
People.objects.extra(select={'young':'if(age < 20, 1, 0)', 
                             'med':'if (age > 20 and age < 50, 1, 0)',
                             'old':'if (age > 50, 1, 0)'}).\
                             values('city').\
                             annotate(sum_young=Sum('young'), 
                                      sum_med=Sum('med'), 
                                      sum_old=Sum('old'))
```

This is not working, seems annotate can't do by calculated fields.

MySQL only solution is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes unfortunately annotation does not work on calculated values, but you can do something like this to achieve what you want:

```
objects = People.objects.extra(select={'young':'if(age < 20, 1, 0)', 
                                       'med':'if (age > 20 and age < 50, 1, 0)',
                                       'old':'if (age > 50, 1, 0)'})
d = {}
for obj in objects:
    if not d.get(obj.city):
        d[obj.city] = {'young': 0, 'med': 0, 'old': 0, objects=[]}
    d[obj.city]['objects'].append(obj)
    if obj.young:
        d[obj.city]['young'] += 1
    elif obj.med:
        d[obj.city]['med'] += 1
    elif obj.old:
        d[obj.city]['old'] += 1
```

Then in `d` dictionary you have cities as keys and then you have young, med, old count and model objects for the city.